# How to use image instead of JText

Tags: joomla-3.x, extensions, mootools

I would like to add an image instead of greeting text "Hello" under that code -

```
$mootoolsButton = $params->get('mootoolsbutton','');
if(empty($mootoolsButton)){
    $mootoolsButton = Jtext::_('Hello');
    // $mootoolsButton = echo '<img src="images/main/nl_03.png" />';
}else{
    if(!empty($mootoolsButton) && preg_match('#^[A-Z_]*$#',$mootoolsButton)){
        $mootoolsButton = JText::_($mootoolsButton);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to use JText in case of rendering images. Just put:

```
$this->mootoolsButton = 'images/main/nl_03.png';
```

JText is used to translate string.

If you are working on custom component then add above code to view.html.php file.
And then access it to "tmpl/default.php" with below code.

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->mootoolsButton; ?>" alt="Button" />
```

Comment: sorry, that line is comment line to note. That's not work to load image. which way can i put that image?

Comment: Are you working on creating custom template or component?

Comment: yes, modifying one module - that module shows only text not image

Comment: ok I updated my answer. For double checking, can you provide the path of your file where you are updating the things. Just making sure, which type of extension you are updating.

Comment: Thanks for replying Sahil Purav, I tried again and again but not worked so I posted at their forum. I gona wait sometimes.

Comment: No Problem, if you can tell me the path of file then I can help you.